# Interpreting replicator dynamic for simplest population model

Tags: theoretical-biology, population-dynamics, evolutionary-game-theory

Suppose the simplest population model where we track the size $y$ of a population:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = ry$$

for a positive constant $r$ and some $y$ such that $y(0) > 0$.

For this population model there is a corresponding "replicator dynamic" model defined by

$$x_0 := \frac{1}{1+y}$$

$$x_1 := \frac{y}{1+y}$$

These are supposed to model "frequencies" of different variants in a population,

QUESTION

except its not clear to me what the different variants here. There is only a single species here so of course it is 100% of its own population or 100% of all populations being modeled here, so I feel that I must be misunderstanding what the "frequencies" of the replicator dynamic are. Can someone clarify what $x_0$ and $x_1$ correspond to here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation carried here is a particular type of the [more general one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_equation#Relationships_to_other_equations). As the linked text notes:

> The continuous replicator equation on n types is equivalent to the Generalized Lotka–Volterra equation in n − 1 dimensions.

In the case described in the OP the number of types is $n=2$, although "Lotka-Volterra" is a bit too generous a term for the simple model in case.

So indeed an extra species is being added here with a zero growth rate. The advantage is that one can now talk about the relative fitness and otherwise use the rich theory developed for the fixed-size populations, since $x_0+x_1=1$ whereas $y$ may grow without limit. E.g., a lot of such intuition comes from the familiarity with Wright-Fisher and Moran models.

Comment: Thank you! Why is that *needed* for the replicator dynamic? I'm interested in using the replicator dynamic to prove ESS (obviously not in this model, instead suppose there are two populations $y_1$ and $y_1$ with growth rates $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively, suppose $r_1 > r_2 > 0$ and I want to prove $y_1$ is an ESS), does the dummy population help for that somehow?

Comment: @John_Krampf one wants the total population to normalize to $1$. If one has two populations, $y_1$ and $y_2$, one could construct $x_1=y_1/(y_1+y_2)$ and $x_2=y_2/(y_1+y_2)$, but this would behave bad when both populations vanish. So $1$ is a kind of pseudocount here. But I must warn, that I am not a game theorist.